# Use LSTM in stable baselines

Tags: lstm, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I'm using PPO2 of stable baselines for RL. My observation space has a shape of (100,10), I would like to replace the network using in the policy by a LSTM, do u know if it's possible?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using stable baselines, then why don't you use the inbuilt [LSTM policy network](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/policies.html#stable_baselines.common.policies.MlpLstmPolicy) itself?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do, but is it possible to choose the numbers of observations to look back?

Comment: is it possible to place a look back limit with lstm in general? or with any rnn in general? and why would you want to do that?